# Alter a trigger is it a DDL statement

Tags: sql, triggers

The following query:

```
Alter trigger myTrigger disable
```

is it a DDL statement?

I found in oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm

```
The DDL statements are:
ALTER ... (All statements beginning with ALTER)
...
```

Comment: DDL means `data definition language`. Functions, procedures, triggers, are not `DDL`s.

Comment: @MihaiStancu, are you sure about that? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language

Comment: @astander the procedures themselves are not DDL, they are specified as part of the SQL/PSM standard extension or the PL/SQL non-standard extension.

Comment: @astander the act of creating a procedure is a DDL.

Comment: If you think, SQL has formed by two branches, DDL and DML you must into two containers all operations. So ALTER TRIGGER I'll put in DDL branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has formed by two branches:

1. Branch DDL: Data Definition Language.
2. Branch DML: Data Manipulating Language.

The first branch works on creation of all structures about a database, the second works on contents in the structure.

I find this article of [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) about Sql Server where you'll find all DDL operations.

And this for [Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands)

And this for [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html)

There are other branches as DCL, TCL but the traditionals are DDL and DML.

I hope this accomplish your question.